# Running One For loop inside another Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to run two for loops, one inside another. The inner loop should run all the way through every time the outer loop runs. I have attached my code but it's not working at the moment. There is also code to write the results to an external csv file, something which I have no idea how to do so if anyone can see any obvious mistakes then that would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
Public Sub Practice1()
Dim UpLim1 As Double, UpLim2 As Double, LowLim1 As Double, LowLim2 As Double
Dim outcome As String, FilePath As String, MtchUIDs As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim SRCUID As String, SNKUID As String

MtchUIDs = ""

FilePath = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\ffpstage1.csv"


Open FilePath For Output As #2

For i = 2 To 91
    For j = 2 To 90

        UpLim1 = Range("d" & i).Value
        LowLim1 = Range("c" & j).Value
        UpLim2 = Range("j" & i).Value
        LowLim2 = Range("i" & j).Value
        SRCUID = Range("a" & i).Value
        SNKUID = Range("g" & j).Value


        If UpLim2 >= LowLim1 And LowLim1 >= LowLim2 Then
           MtchUIDs = SRCUID & SNKUID

        ElseIf UpLim1 > LowLim2 And LowLim2 >= LowLim1 Then
            MtchUIDs = SRCUID & SNKUID

             Write #2, MtchUIDs
             MtchUIDs = ""
        Else
             Next j

        End If

Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: In what way is it *not working at the moment*?  The more detial you can provide the more likely it is we can help you.

Comment: When I try to run, the compile error is 'Next without For', and the 'Next j' section of text is highlighted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `End If` within the `For j` loop, try this for the loops:

```
For i = 2 To 91
    For j = 2 To 90

        UpLim1 = Range("d" & i).Value
        LowLim1 = Range("c" & j).Value
        UpLim2 = Range("j" & i).Value
        LowLim2 = Range("i" & j).Value
        SRCUID = Range("a" & i).Value
        SNKUID = Range("g" & j).Value

        If UpLim2 >= LowLim1 And LowLim1 >= LowLim2 Then
           MtchUIDs = SRCUID & SNKUID
        ElseIf UpLim1 > LowLim2 And LowLim2 >= LowLim1 Then
            MtchUIDs = SRCUID & SNKUID
            Write #2, MtchUIDs
            MtchUIDs = ""
        End if

    Next j

Next i
```